# Jetty Embedded - PUT Verb - Process headers before the body arrives

Tags: java, jetty, embedded-jetty

I'm using Jetty 9 and I'm trying to process the headers of a PUT request before all the body has arrived on the server. Here's what I've done:

Server.java:

```
public class SimplestServer
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        Server server = new Server(9080);

        ServletHandler handler = new ServletHandler();
        server.setHandler(handler);

        handler.addServletWithMapping(HelloServlet.class, "/*");
        handler.addFilterWithMapping(HelloPrintingFilter.class, "/*", EnumSet.of(DispatcherType.REQUEST));

        server.start();
        server.dumpStdErr();
        server.join();
    }

    public static class HelloServlet extends HttpServlet {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @Override
        protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
            System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis() + ": Hello from HelloServlet GET");
        }

        @Override
        protected void doPut(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
            System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis() + ": Hello from HelloServlet PUT");
        }
    }

    public static class HelloPrintingFilter implements Filter {
        @Override
        public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
        throws IOException, ServletException {
            System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis() + ": Hello from filter");
            chain.doFilter(request, response);
        }

        @Override
        public void init(FilterConfig arg0) throws ServletException {
            System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis() + ": Init from filter");
        }

        @Override
        public void destroy() {
            System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis() + ": Destroy from filter");
        }
    }
}
```

Client.java

```
public class SimplestClient
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        URL url = new URL("http://localhost:9080/resource");
        HttpURLConnection httpCon = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        httpCon.setDoOutput(true);
        httpCon.setRequestMethod("PUT");
        OutputStream out = httpCon.getOutputStream();
        byte[] b = new byte[65536];
        Random r = new Random();
        r.nextBytes(b);
        for (int i = 0; i < 1024; i++) {
            out.write(b);
        }
        System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis() + ": Data sent. Waiting 5 seconds...");

        try {
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        out.close();
        System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis() + ": Done!");
        httpCon.getInputStream();
    }
}
```

In a nutshell, the server program listens for connections on port `9080`, when a request arrives the filter `HelloPrintingFilter` gets executed, then the request is processed by the `HelloServlet`. The client, instead, connects to the server, sends a bunch of data, then sleeps for 5 seconds and finally closes the connection with the server.

A run of both programs yields the following result:

Client:

```
1469613522350: Data sent. Waiting 5 seconds...
1469613527351: Done!
```

Server:

```
1469613527373: Hello from filter
1469613527373: Hello from HelloServlet PUT
```

Looking at the timestamps I can only get my filter code executed after all the body has arrived. Could anyone explain me how to do it? A typical use case is: a client tries to upload a 5GB file. As soon as the headers arrive, I want to check if they are OK (e.g. by checking if the Content-MD5 header, or whatever custom header I need to check, is present). If the request is OK then start processing the body. If the request is not OK then close the connection.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gotcha! The problem was not in the server side, but in the client side, which was only intended as a stub. Specifically, the problem was the buffering in the `HttpUrlConnection`.

Recalling my `client.java`, I have:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 1024; i++) {
        out.write(b);
    }
```

and if I change the loop to something like

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 1024*1024; i++) {
        out.write(b);
    }
```

I immediately get an `OutOfMemoryError` exception, getting nothing on the server side, indicating that no single byte was transferred. And of course it is right, because BEFORE putting the headers on the wire the `HttpUrlConnection` needs to know the body length since it must emit the `Content-Length` header. Changing the client implementation to raw sockets, effectively controlling when bytes go to the wire, resolved the issue.

As a side note, the server code can be further simplified by removing the filter class. The complete server-side code is:

server.java:

```
public class SimplestServer
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        Server server = new Server(9080);

        ServletHandler handler = new ServletHandler();
        server.setHandler(handler);

        handler.addServletWithMapping(HelloServlet.class, "/*");

        server.start();
        server.dumpStdErr();
        server.join();
    }

    public static class HelloServlet extends HttpServlet {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @Override
        protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
            System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis() + ": Hello from HelloServlet GET");
        }

        @Override
        protected void doPut(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
            System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis() + ": Hello from HelloServlet PUT");

            // Perform some checks here
            if (request.getHeader("X-Key") == null)
            {
                response.setHeader("Connection", "close");
                response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_FORBIDDEN);
                System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis() + ": Filter --> X-Key failed!");
                return;
            }

            // Everything OK! Read the stream.
            System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis() + ": Proceded!!");
            InputStream body = request.getInputStream();
            long bytesReadSoFar = 0;
            byte[] data = new byte[65536];
            while (true) {
                int bytesRead = body.read(data);
                if (bytesRead < 0)
                    break;
                bytesReadSoFar += bytesRead;
            }
            System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis() + ": Finished! Read " + bytesReadSoFar + " bytes.");
            response.setHeader("Connection", "close");
            response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Incorrect assumptions.  It is perfectly valid/legal to send request and/or response body content without a `Content-Length` header, that is known as [chunked transfer encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding), which Jetty supports out of the box both as a client and/or server.

Answer (score 0):

Use multiple requests. e.g. first request includes custom header and subsequent requests are used to upload a 5GB file.

Comment: Sorry, this is not an option. I need to do this for each request on the server side, because I don't have any sort of control on "other's" clients implementation.

Comment: Http is based on TCP. No worry about the server if the client don't close the http connection, timeout will be triggered and if the data size of request is enough, the server will recieve the partial data, such as, http headers... parsing the HTTP request is ok. Now check headers, if rejecting, you can close it regardless of the client.

Comment: This is wrong. The server (Jetty) is always getting partial data. The problem is that Jetty seems not to give me the option to check the headers of the request when the headers arrived, or while the body is still arriving, be it 5k or 5MB or 5GB. It will ingest ALL the data before triggering my filter code. But reality is that the server should never ingest 5GB of data if after about 1k (the header) it already knows it can drop the connection.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't doing anything in your `HelloServlet.doPut()`, so you are basically telling the Servlet container (aka Jetty) that you are done handling that request.

The request processing in Jetty is handled by a series of buffers from the network.

Your PUT headers and the start of your body content likely fit in a single buffer.

Jetty will parse the headers out, and then start the dispatch of the request to the Servlet chain, hitting your `HelloFilter`, and then your filter moves it along the chain with the `chain.doFilter(request, response);`

The point in time when `HelloServlet.doPut()` is reached, the headers have been processed, and the start of the body content hasn't, waiting for your implementation in `doPut()` to call `HttpServletRequest.getInputStream()` and start processing it, at which point Jetty is free to start reading more buffers off the network.

> Note: if your servlet exits without reading the request input stream, and the response hasn't indicated a `Connection: close`, then Jetty will be forced to read the entire request to completion looking for the next request after it (known as a [persistent connection](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-6.3) in HTTP/1.1 spec)

The closest you'll get to reaching your stated goal to reject the Request body content is to use what you have available in the HTTP/1.1 spec (assuming this is a HTTP/1.1 request).  Namely a proper response status code and a server initiated `Connection: close` response header.

Here's a complete example:

```java
package jetty;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.StringWriter;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.DefaultHandler;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection;
import org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler;
import org.eclipse.jetty.util.IO;
import org.eclipse.jetty.util.Uptime;
import org.junit.AfterClass;
import org.junit.BeforeClass;
import org.junit.Test;

public class PutRejectExample
{
    public static class RejectServlet extends HttpServlet
    {
        @Override
        protected void doPut(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException
        {
            timedLog("doPut() - enter");
            if (req.getHeader("X-Key") == null)
            {
                resp.setHeader("Connection", "close");
                resp.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_FORBIDDEN);
                timedLog("doPut() - rejected");
                return;
            }
            
            File output = File.createTempFile("reject-", ".dat");
            try (FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(output))
            {
                IO.copy(req.getInputStream(), out);
            }
            resp.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
            resp.setHeader("Connection", "close"); // be a good HTTP/1.1 citizen
            timedLog("doPut() - exit");
        }
    }
    
    private static Server server;
    private static int port;
    
    private static void timedLog(String format, Object... args)
    {
        System.out.printf(Uptime.getUptime() + "ms " + format + "%n", args);
    }
    
    @BeforeClass
    public static void startServer() throws Exception
    {
        server = new Server();
        ServerConnector connector = new ServerConnector(server);
        connector.setPort(0);
        server.addConnector(connector);
        
        // collection for handlers
        HandlerCollection handlers = new HandlerCollection();
        server.setHandler(handlers);
        
        // servlet context
        ServletContextHandler context = new ServletContextHandler();
        context.addServlet(RejectServlet.class, "/reject");
        handlers.addHandler(context);
        
        // default handler
        handlers.addHandler(new DefaultHandler());
        
        // start server
        server.start();
        
        // grab port
        port = connector.getLocalPort();
    }
    
    @AfterClass
    public static void stopServer() throws Exception
    {
        server.stop();
    }
    
    private void performPUT(int requestSize, String... extraRequestHeaders) throws IOException
    {
        StringBuilder req = new StringBuilder();
        req.append("PUT /reject HTTP/1.1\r\n");
        req.append("Host: localhost:").append(port).append("\r\n");
        req.append("Content-Length: ").append(requestSize).append("\r\n");
        for (String extraHeader : extraRequestHeaders)
        {
            req.append(extraHeader);
        }
        req.append("\r\n");
        
        timedLog("client open connection");
        try (Socket socket = new Socket())
        {
            socket.connect(new InetSocketAddress("localhost", port));
            
            try (OutputStream out = socket.getOutputStream();
                 InputStream in = socket.getInputStream();
                 InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(in))
            {
                timedLog("client send request (headers + body)");
                try
                {
                    // write request line + headers
                    byte headerBytes[] = req.toString().getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
                    out.write(headerBytes);
                    out.flush();
                    
                    // write put body content
                    int bufSize = 65535;
                    byte[] buf = new byte[bufSize];
                    int sizeLeft = requestSize;
                    while (sizeLeft > 0)
                    {
                        int writeSize = Math.min(sizeLeft, bufSize);
                        ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextBytes(buf);
                        out.write(buf, 0, writeSize);
                        out.flush();
                        sizeLeft -= writeSize;
                        try
                        {
                            // simulate a slower connection
                            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(10);
                        }
                        catch (InterruptedException ignore)
                        {
                            // ignore
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (IOException e)
                {
                    timedLog("client request send exception");
                    e.printStackTrace(System.out);
                }
                timedLog("client send request complete");
                
                timedLog("client read response");
                try
                {
                    StringWriter respStream = new StringWriter();
                    IO.copy(reader, respStream);
                    
                    timedLog("client response: %s", respStream.toString());
                }
                catch (IOException e)
                {
                    timedLog("client read response exception");
                    e.printStackTrace(System.out);
                }
            }
        }
        timedLog("client connection complete");
    }
    
    @Test
    public void testBadPost() throws IOException
    {
        timedLog("---- testBadPost()");
        performPUT(1024 * 1024 * 10);
    }
    
    @Test
    public void testGoodPost() throws IOException
    {
        timedLog("---- testGoodPost()");
        performPUT(1024 * 1024 * 10, "X-Key: foo\r\n");
    }
}
```

This uses raw `Socket` and raw streams to avoid getting confused by all of the buffering present in the `HttpUrlConnection`.

The output you'll see for the normal / happy case is like this ...

```
416ms ---- testGoodPost()
416ms client open connection
2016-07-27 06:40:22.180:INFO:oejs.AbstractConnector:main: Started ServerConnector@55f3ddb1{HTTP/1.1,[http/1.1]}{0.0.0.0:46748}
2016-07-27 06:40:22.181:INFO:oejs.Server:main: Started @414ms
421ms client send request (headers + body)
494ms doPut() - enter
2084ms doPut() - exit
2093ms client send request complete
2093ms client read response
2094ms client response: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Wed, 27 Jul 2016 13:40:22 GMT
Connection: close
Server: Jetty(9.3.11.v20160721)
2094ms client connection complete
```

The output for the rejected case will look like this ...

```
2095ms ---- testBadPost()
2095ms client open connection
2096ms client send request (headers + body)
2096ms doPut() - enter
2101ms doPut() - rejected
2107ms client request send exception
java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:109)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:153)
    at jetty.PutRejectExample.performPUT(PutRejectExample.java:137)
    at jetty.PutRejectExample.testBadPost(PutRejectExample.java:180)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
2109ms client send request complete
2109ms client read response
2109ms client response: HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
Date: Wed, 27 Jul 2016 13:40:23 GMT
Cache-Control: must-revalidate,no-cache,no-store
Content-Type: text/html;charset=iso-8859-1
Content-Length: 322
Connection: close
Server: Jetty(9.3.11.v20160721)

<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1"/>
<title>Error 403 </title>
</head>
<body>
<h2>HTTP ERROR: 403</h2>
<p>Problem accessing /reject. Reason:
<pre>    Forbidden</pre></p>
<hr /><a href="http://eclipse.org/jetty">Powered by Jetty:// 9.3.11-SNAPSHOT</a><hr/>
</body>
</html>

2109ms client connection complete
```